# Ethernet port not showing in device manager (lan not working)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-10, drivers, ethernet

My Ethernet port was causing troubles (in windows) within a few weeks after installing ubuntu but it did worked on ubuntu. Somehow It worked on windows after un-installing the driver and rebooting to windows. I stopping un-installing and re-installing the driver and just used wifi on windows but recently when I switched to ubuntu it stopped showing the lan (networking setting also dosen't have ethernet settings) and when I rebooted to windows the network and sharing center dosen't show ethernet. I am new to linux so don't know much. I tried to scan for hardware changes but nothing changed in device manager.

I now have two problems.
a) Which driver to install?
b) After installing it should work on both OS.

[device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOtwF.png)

Answer (score 1):

So, the problems for accessing your ethernet device on windows and ubuntu are generally completely separate, but in your case it *might* be related to hardware issues. For your ethernet device to work sometimes and others not at all might be an indication of some type of hardware issue.

In windows, be sure to goto your device manager and look for your ethernet card. It may have some conflicts or a yellow ! sign next to it to indicate some other problem.

In Ubuntu you can do a simple ifconfig -a command in a shell to see if your device is even showing up at all. Network manager usually handles everything automatically but it does have some issues..

Comment: I added the device manager status in the question, it doesn't show any errors there. It doesn't even show the Ethernet card.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it just started working automatically while running the windows just crashed and when it rebooted lan port began to work.